# How to check if the tiff is color space indexed using TiffBitmapDecoder?

Tags: c#, windows, image, bitmap, .net-4.5

```
 var multiTiff = new TiffBitmapDecoder(tiffImgStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
```

I can use the FormatConvertedBitmap class to convert the pixel format but first how can I check the each frame is color space indexed in this multi tiff?

Comment: [BitmapDecoder.Palette](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder.palette%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

The comment by TaW is correct. The presence of a palette in a TIFF page is a good indicator of that page being color indexed. You can use this code:

```
for (int frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < multiTiff.Frames.Count; ++frameNumber)
  if (multiTiff.Frames[frameNumber].Palette == null)
    MessageBox.Show("Not indexed");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("indexed");
```